# Spring framework serialize not working for JSON that has a key with an underscore

Tags: java, spring, serialization, deserialization

I am using the the following version of the spring framework:

```
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
```

My json object is given below

```
    {
    "temp":20.94,
    "temp_min":20.94,
    }
```

Notice that one of the keys has an underscore (temp_min).
My model is as follows:

```
private double temp_min;

public double getTempMin() {
    return this.temp_min;
}

public void setTempMin(double temp_min) {
    this.temp_min = temp_min;
}
private double temp;

public double getTemp() {
    return this.temp;
}

public void setTemp(double temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
}
```

Temp is set correctly, but "temp_min" is not set.

I tried `@JsonProperty("temp_min")` above the getter, setter, and variable declaration.

I am using spring framework's default serialization.
Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: I have tried     @JsonProperty("temp_min") above getter, setter and variable declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  annotation on variable

```
    @JsonProperty(temp_min)
    private double temp_min;
```

Also add on class name

```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do want to annotate the variable,
but you also want to annotate it correctly.

Use exactly one of these solutions:

1) Annotate the private variable with @JsonProperty.

```
@JsonProperty("temp_min")
private double temp_min
```

2) Annotate the setter (and getter, if needed)

```
@JsonSetter("temp_min")
public void setTempMin(...)
{
    ...
}

@JsonGetter("temp_min")
public double getTempMin()
{
    ...
}
```

3) Annotate the setter (and getter, if needed) using @JsonProperty

```
@JsonProperty("temp_min")
public void setTempMin(...)
{
    ...
}

@JsonProperty("temp_min")
public double getTempMin()
{
    ...
}
```